# Exception: Unable to send e-mail: no recipient

Tags: javascript, email, spreadsheet

Honestly I'm lost. I'm trying to send email responses from a spreadsheet, found this script, edited it a bit and now it won't send emails. This goes beyond my knowledge so now I'm here. Someone please help me out.

```js
// add menu to Sheet
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  ui.createMenu("Send Emails")
  .addItem("Send Email Batch","createEmail")
  .addToUi();
}

/**
 * take the range of data in sheet
 * use it to build an HTML email body
 */
function createEmail() {
  var thisWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thisSheet = thisWorkbook.getSheetByName('Formulierreacties 1');
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = thisSheet.getLastRow();

  // get the data range of the sheet
  var allRange = thisSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, thisSheet.getLastColumn());
  
  // get all the data in this range
  var allData = allRange.getValues();
  
  // get the header row
  var headers = allData.shift();
  
  // create header index map
  var headerIndexes = indexifyHeaders(headers);
  
  allData.forEach(function(row,i) {
    if (!row[headerIndexes["Status"]]) {
      var   htmlBody = 
        `Hi,

          Thanks for filling in the warning appeal!

            Your answers:

              What is your user ID?
              ${row[headerIndexes["What is your user ID?"]]}

              What was the case ID of your warning?
              ${row[headerIndexes["What was the case ID of your warning?"]]}

              What was the reason for your warning?
              ${row[headerIndexes["What was the reason for your warning?"]]}

              How many points were you warned for?
              ${row[headerIndexes["How many points were you warned for?"]]}

              Did this warning lead to you being banned from the server?
              ${row[headerIndexes["Did this warning lead to you being banned from the server?"]]}

              Why do you think this warning should be lifted?
              ${row[headerIndexes["Why do you think this warning should be lifted?"]]}

                Reply:

                ${row[headerIndexes["Custom Reply"]]} 
 
                  Have a great day.

                    Regards,

                      JavaScript Universe Management Team`;
      
      var timestamp = sendEmail(row[headerIndexes["E-mailadres"]],htmlBody);
      thisSheet.getRange(i + 2, headerIndexes["Status"] + 1).setValue(timestamp);
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("No email sent for this row: " + i + 1);
    }
  });
}
  

/**
 * create index from column headings
 * @param {[object]} headers is an array of column headings
 * @return {{object}} object of column headings as key value pairs with index number
 */
function indexifyHeaders(headers) {
  
  var index = 0;
  return headers.reduce (
    // callback function
    function(p,c) {
    
      //skip cols with blank headers
      if (c) {
        // can't have duplicate column names
        if (p.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
          throw new Error('duplicate column name: ' + c);
        }
        p = index;
      }
      index++;
      return p;
    },
    {} // initial value for reduce function to use as first argument
  );
}

/**
 * send email from GmailApp service
 * @param {string} recipient is the email address to send email to
 * @param {string} body is the html body of the email
 * @return {object} new date object to write into spreadsheet to confirm email sent
 */
function sendEmail(recipient,body) {
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    recipient,
    "Thanks for filling in the warning appeal!", 
    "",
    {
      htmlBody: body
    }
  );
  
  return new Date();
}
```

There's probs a lot wrong with this, but I just don't see it. I'm gonna look into it more, but I hope the wonderful smart developers of (Heaven) stackoverflow could see the issue and resolve it for me. I normally don't ask to be spoon feed, but I have been staring at this for about 2 hours, got a headache, and officially lost and feeling like a complete and utter idiot.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is there any error message given?

Comment: Based on the error message, is it possible there's a typo in `row[headerIndexes["E-mailadres"]]`?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to debug this stuff, it's not like I can log it to a console, or can I? I have Googled my issue and couldn't find anything useful. No errors either, the only thing it says is Exception: Unable to send e-mail: no recipient...

Comment: "Based on the error message, is it possible there's a typo in row[headerIndexes["E-mailadres"]]?" 

It's copied straight from the sheet.

Comment: Here's how to log in Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging Try logging the `recipient` in your `sendEmail` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead pushing lines and lines of code and realize at the end of the week that nothing work, start to code step by step.
Just try to make this line working:

`GmailApp.sendEmail( "put your email here", 'this is a test', "and it work");`

If it doesn't work, maybe:

- GmailApp is not initialized, so the mail is not send
- you see no mail cause they goes into spam, try to send them to a mailer without any spam system.

If it works, change you call, you're content is no html, maybe this is the mistake

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(
    recipient,
    "Thanks for filling in the warning appeal!", 
    body
  );
```

If it is no working, add the following line just before:

```
console.log('Sending email to', recipient);
```

And check recipient is correct.